How to get the next timestamp based on column condition in SQL?
I have a table that looks like this



event_d
event_lcl_ts
location_id
event_code
container_id




4/6/24
2024-04-06T10:19:32.133+00:00
1
PUTAWAY
asdjhdf-323


4/6/24
2024-04-06T21:52:35.019+00:00
1
RECEIVE
asdjhdf-323


4/7/24
2024-04-07T00:13:17.496+00:00
1
PUTAWAY
asdjhdf-323


4/7/24
2024-04-07T12:35:54.766+00:00
1
RECEIVE
asdjhdf-323


4/7/24
2024-04-07T16:27:13.245+00:00
1
PUTAWAY
asdjhdf-323


4/8/24
2024-04-08T22:56:19.038+00:00
1
RECEIVE
asdjhdf-323


4/9/24
2024-04-09T00:19:47.575+00:00
1
PUTAWAY
asdjhdf-323


4/10/24
2024-04-10T20:44:12.190+00:00
1
RECEIVE
asdjhdf-323


4/11/24
2024-04-11T01:14:45.466+00:00
1
PUTAWAY
asdjhdf-323


4/11/24
2024-04-11T10:14:12.709+00:00
1
RECEIVE
asdjhdf-323


4/11/24
2024-04-11T12:57:11.640+00:00
1
PUTAWAY
asdjhdf-323



I am trying to create a row where it shows the timestamp when the container was received and then put away which is based on the event_code. One caveat of this data is that there will be instances where a PUTAWAY event will be populated without its prior RECEIVE event based on the timeframe of the data pulled. There can also be cases where the PUTAWAY event has not occurred yet over the most recent RECEIVE event.
In this scenario by ideal output would be this:



container_id
receive_timestamp
putaway_timestamp
location_id




asdjhdf-323
2024-04-06T21:52:35.019+00:00
2024-04-07T00:13:17.496+00:00
1


asdjhdf-323
2024-04-07T12:35:54.766+00:00
2024-04-07T16:27:13.245+00:00
1


asdjhdf-323
2024-04-08T22:56:19.038+00:00
2024-04-09T00:19:47.575+00:00
1


asdjhdf-323
2024-04-10T20:44:12.190+00:00
2024-04-11T01:14:45.466+00:00
1


asdjhdf-323
2024-04-11T10:14:12.709+00:00
2024-04-11T12:57:11.640+00:00
1



How can I do this while ignoring or filtering cases where there might be PUTAWAY events before RECEIVE? In this case - the first row. Thanks!

What happens if there are two or three PUTAWAY or RECEIVE events conseecutively?

is the a 7/24 hour process? and a related receive/putaway pair can occur on different days? (i.e either side of midnight)

There will never be two or three of the same events in a row, they will always alternate. It is a 24 hour process so they can occur on different days.

So what do you mean "How can I do this while ignoring or filtering cases where there might be PUTAWAY events before RECEIVE? In this case - the first row." ?

because this data is landed in real time, and with the filtering  there might be cases where the first record for this container is a "PUTAWAY" event rather than a "RECEIVE". The "RECEIVE" event happens first so I need to start with the first "RECEIVE" event and then get the next "PUTAWAY" timestamp.
so in this example the first row needs to be ignored because that corresponding "RECEIVE" record is not present. Hope that helps

Looks like you can just use LAG or LEAD if you are sure that the row are always interleaved.
SELECT
  t.container_id,
  t.event_lcl_ts AS receive_timestamp,
  t.putaway_timestamp,
  t.location_id
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
      LEAD(CASE WHEN t.event_code = 'PUTAWAY' THEN t.event_lcl_ts END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY t.location_id, t.container_id ORDER BY t.event_lcl_ts) AS putaway_timestamp
    FROM YourTable AS t
) AS t
WHERE t.event_code = 'RECEIVE';


Changing this to LEAD instead of LAG got me what I needed, thanks!
